# How to find the type of roots for four degree polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

Let $P(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 − 8x^2 − 1$. Which of the following is false?

(A) $P(x)$ has a real root in $(−4, 1)$

(B) $P(x)$ has a real root $< −4$

(C) $P(x)$ has a real root $> 1$

(D) $P(x)$ has at least two real roots

What I had learned so far was to find the type of roots for three degree polynomials. Will the method of finding the type of roots for four degree polynomials be same?

Comment: This problem does **not** ask you to find any roots!  It is easy to calculate that when x= -4 that polynomial is positive and when x= 1 it is negative so there is at least one point where it is 0 and, if more than one, still an odd number.  The degree is 4 so there cannot be more than 4 roots- there are either 1 or 3 roots in that interval.  For very large x, either positive or negative. $x^4$ dominates- the polynomial is eventually positive so we know there is one more root larger than 1.

Comment: Spoilers, your answer is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%28x%29+%3D+x%5E4+%2B+4x%5E3+%E2%88%92+8x%5E2+%E2%88%92+1+solve+for+x)

Answer (score 2):

By Descarte's rule $f(x)=0$ has atmost one real positive root as their is only one sign change in $f(x).$ The number of sign changes in $f(-x)$ is one so, this equation has atmost one negative root. Thus this equation has at most two real roots.

$f'(x)=4x(x^2+3x-4)=0$ has roots as $x=0,1,-4$. Next, $f''(x)=12x^2+24x$ implies that  $f''(0)=0, f''(1)>0, f''(-4)>0$ because of change in the sign of $f'(x)$ around zero from positive to negative, there is a max at $x=0$.
$f_{max}=f(0)=-1$ and $f_{min}=f(-4)<0$ , $f_{min}=f(1)<0.$ There are only two real roots. Further, as  $f(0)=-1<0, f(2)>0$ there is one real root in $(0,2)$, Next, f(-4)<0 and f(-6)>0, there is another real root in $(-5,-6).$

Since $f(x)$ has negative min at $x=-4$, so one real root can be asserted to be $<-4$. Similarly, $f(x)$ has negative min at $x=1$, $f(x)$ can be asserted to have a real rot for $x>1$.

So options (B) and (C) are correct and the equation has exactly two real roots, so the statement (D) is also true.

Comment: $D$ is correct as well :)

Comment: No, it has exactly two real roots.

Comment: That is not how you read "At least two real roots". Exactly two will count within that. Otherwise you are suggesting two options are incorrect but the question asks for only one option that is false.

Answer (score 1):

Since the coefficient of $x^4$ is positive, we now that $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} P(x) = +\infty > 0. $$
Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
P(-4) &= -129 < 0,\\
P(1) &= -4 < 0.
\end{align*}
Hence, $P$ must change sign and hence have zeroes both in $(-\infty, -4)$ and $(1,+\infty)$, so B), C) and D) are true.

Since the question implies one of the statements is false, it has to A).

If you want to verify that A) is false, see if $P$ has a positive local maximum in $(-4,1)$ using the zeroes of the degree three polynomial $P'$.

Comment: At $x=0$, we have $P=-1, P'=0$ and $P''=-16$, which settles the issue.